# Count student per course from a csv file using base python ( no pandas or any outside library)

Tags: python-3.x

> **enroll_code,student_id**
>
> 10030,55000
>
> 10030,55804
>
> 10250,55804
>
> 10510,55000

the data is shown, I need code that shows number of students **enroll_code** and should look like this

> 10030: 2
>
> 10250: 1
>
> 10510: 1

```
import csv
data=[]
with open('D:/Download_Ddrive/Data.csv','r') as csvFile:
    reader = csv.reader(csvFile)
    for row in reader:
    data.append(row)
    print(data)
csvFile.close()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- Use split to separate the enroll code from student_id
- You can use a dictionary to count. Even better if you want to use stuff from collections package but I suppose you want to avoid that
- Depends on your application, you might want to use int to convert string to int.

  ```
  data = [ '10030,55000', '10030,55804', '10250,55804', '10510,55000']

  course_dict = dict()
  for sub_data in data:
      key, value = sub_data.split(',')
      if key in course_dict:
          course_dict[key] += 1
      else:
          course_dict[key] = 1
  for key in course_dict:
      print(key,": " , course_dict[key])
  ```

would gives me:

```
10030 :  2
10250 :  1
10510 :  1
```

Answer (score 0):

```
res1=[]
for entries in data:
if entries.count('10030')>=1:
    sum_10030=entries.count('10030')>=1
    res1.append(sum_10030)
print("10030 : " + str(res1.count(True)))

res2=[]
for entries in data:
if entries.count('10250')>=1:
    sum_10250=entries.count('10250')>=1
    res2.append(sum_10250)
print("10250 : " + str(res2.count(True)))

res3=[]
for entries in data:
if entries.count('10510')>=1:
    sum_10510=entries.count('10510')>=1
    res3.append(sum_10510)
print("10250 : " + str(res3.count(True)))
```

Answer (score 0):

python comes with builtin [Counter](https://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.Counter) class which makes the job much shorter (1 liner)

```
from collections import Counter

data = ['10030,55000', '10030,55804', '10250,55804', '10510,55000']

counter = Counter(entry.split(',')[0] for entry in data)
print(counter)
```

Output

```
Counter({'10030': 2, '10250': 1, '10510': 1})
```